# injective holomorphic maps from $\mathbb{C}$\ {$0$} onto itself.

Tags: complex-analysis

Describe all the injective holomorphic maps from $\mathbb{C}$\ {$0$}
onto itself.

I am guessing I need to use open mapping theorem here but otherwise I dont know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer.** $\,f(z)=az\,$ or $\,f(z)=a/z$, for some $a\ne 0$.

Hint. At $z=0$ the function $f$ has an isolated singularity. It can only be a removable one or a simple pole. If it is removable, $f$ should vanish there.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what kind of singularity can such a map have at $0$?

Comment: Removable  Singularity ?

Comment: That's one possibllity.